# python pandas dataframe variable not updating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on creating a program that will pull some data from a preformatted file that does not include a timestamp but requires one. I know the following things:

1. The name of the file, which includes that hour at which the data was logged. I can assume that the first data point was collected at the start of the hour and I can parse that.
2. I know that each data point was collected at a frequency of 64Hz, so I know the time delta between each data point.

As I write the code chunk to extract these data, I am running into this problem that my date is updating, but my hour isn't. The result is that all my data have the correct date, but the same hour. I'm hoping this is just the result of missing something logical as a result of sleep deprivation, but I'd appreciate it if someone could point out the problem with my code.

```
#Paths for files to process
advpath = '/Users/stnixon/Dropbox/GradSchool/Research/EddyCovarianceData/data/palmyra2016/**'

#Create list of files to process
advfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(advpath,'*.A16'))

#create data frames, load files, concatenate, and sort adv files and dfetfiles
advframe = []

for f in advfiles:
    advdf = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+', names=['ID','u','v','w','u1','v1','w1','ucorr','vcorr','wcorr'], usecols=[0,1,2,3,7,8,9])
    file_now = os.path.basename(f)
    print(int(file_now[4:6]))
    advdf['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(int(file_now[4:6]),unit='h')
    advdf['Date'] = pd.to_datetime('2016'+file_now[0:2]+file_now[2:4])
    advframe.append(advdf)
advdata = pd.concat(advframe)
```

Essentially, the Date column gives me the right date across each row, while the Time column just gives me the same value for all.

Comment: can you provide a sample of data if possible?

Comment: Absolutely! For a file named 06281200.A16 every line looks like this: 1604   -234   -223    682  78  83  82  92  91  90. The first number is an useless ID, the next three are velocity in the x,y, and z directions, the next 3 are a correction value for each dimension and the last three are a correlation for each dimension.

Comment: What happens if you insert `advdf['Time'] = advdf.Time.dt.hour` right after `advdf['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(int(file_now[4:6]),unit='h')`? Does it show the same values still?

Comment: Same values. The problem isn't the formatting so much as getting the values to actually update...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was not a bug, but instead a weird coincidence. The files I needed to process were parsing the hour correctly, but they were being processed in a random order and it just so happens that the hours for the first two and last two files were all the same. So it looked in the terminal as if it wasn't updating.